# What's interfering with my scoped type variables here?

Tags: haskell, scoped-type-variables

*I've been dreading asking this question for the last couple of days since it has the hallmarks of me not noticing a small mistake, so I sincerely apologize if that is the case.*

I am trying to write my own `scanr` as a part of a library I am writing.  The code looks like the following:

```
-- Language Extensions for the file --
{-# Language BangPatterns #-}
{-# Language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# Language FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# Language QuantifiedConstraints #-}
{-# Language UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

rightScan ::
  ( Foldable f
  )
    => forall a b . (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> NonEmpty [] b
rightScan g start as = start :| reverse (rightFold addOn [] as)
  where
    addOn :: a -> [b] -> [b]
    addOn new (c : cs) = g new c : c : cs
    addOn new [] = [g new start]
```

(My `NonEmpty` is actually parameterized by a container (in this case `[]`), my `NonEmpty []` is equivalent to the traditional `NonEmpty`.)

Now this has an two errors:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a1’
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      addOn :: forall a1 b1. a1 -> [b1] -> [b1]
```

and the very similar

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘b1’
  ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      addOn :: forall a1 b1. a1 -> [b1] -> [b1]
```

Now these errors are pretty easy to understand.  It considers the `a` in `rightScran`'s signature to be different from `a` in `addOn`'s signature and the same with `b`.  However I have scoped type variables on and both those variables are introduced with a `forall` in the parent.

Now I can just remove the signature of `addOn` to resolve the issue, but I am utterly baffled as to why scoped type variables is not working here.

So the question is: What am I doing wrong with my scoped type variables here?

Comment: Could you include the whole error message? I realize it's crazy verbose, but that verbosity usually includes the problem and is easier to use than ignore.

Comment: That said... Those error messages make it look very much like ScopedTypeVariables isn't enabled. The problem might be elsewhere in your file. Can you give us a complete file showing this problem - ideally minimized as much as possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the location of the `forall`.  It needs to come before the constraint and list all type variables, including `f`.  `forall f a b. (Foldable f) => ...`.

The way you've written it, the forall doesn't scope over the entire type, so the type variables it binds are considered local to the type. This is enabled by `RankNTypes`, which is included in `QuantifiedConstraints`.

Comment: `QuantifiedConstraints` does imply `RankNTypes`, thank you.